# ROS on Ubuntu Core Issues

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap, ros

I am having some problems with Ubuntu Core and ROS. I am using Snapcraft. I was able to do the "create your first snap" tutorial (https://snapcraft.io/docs/build-snaps/your-first-snap) and everything was fine.

Then I followed the ROS tutorial (https://github.com/snapcore/snapcraft/blob/master/docs/ros-snap.md). Instead of doing a talker and a listener I just have one "hello world" node that outputs a message to the screen. I am able to build and install just fine, but on running I get the following output:

```
$USER@localhost:~$ ros-example.launch-project  
... logging to /home/$USER/snap/ros-example/x1/ros/log/a413e04a-efb3-11e6-bf45-3d232f894a41/roslaunch-localhost.localdomain-7392.log 
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile. 
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt

Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "/snap/ros-example/x1/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 307, in main
      p.start()   
  File "/snap/ros-example/x1/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 268, in start
    self._start_infrastructure()
  File "/snap/ros-example/x1/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 217, in _start_infrastructure
    self._load_config()   
  File "/snap/ros-example/x1/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/parent.py", line 132, in _load_config
    roslaunch_strs=self.roslaunch_strs, verbose=self.verbose)   
  File "/snap/ros-example/x1/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/config.py", line 471, in load_config_default
    config.assign_machines()   
  File "/snap/ros-example/x1/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/config.py", line 222, in assign_machines
    if [m for m in machine_unify_dict.values() if not is_machine_local(m)]:   
  File "/snap/ros-example/x1/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/core.py", line 97, in is_machine_local
    local_addresses = ['localhost'] + rosgraph.network.get_local_addresses()   
  File "/snap/ros-example/x1/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/network.py", line 218, in get_local_addresses
    for iface in netifaces.interfaces(): 
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I have added the install rules for the .cpp, .hpp, and .launch files in the cmake list, and running the `roslaunch` command works to run the node. But running in the Core environment as a snap does not work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my cmakelist:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(hello_world)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package()

include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(write_prompt src/write_prompt.cpp)
target_link_libraries(write_prompt ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

install(TARGETS write_prompt
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
  PATTERN "*.hpp"
  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
)

install(FILES
  launch/run_code.launch
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)
```

And my snapcraft.yaml:

```
name: ros-example
version: 1.0
summary: ROS Example
description: Runs a modified Hello World node
confinement: strict

apps:
  launch-project:
    command: roslaunch hello_world run_code.launch

parts:
  ros-project:
    plugin: catkin
    source: .
    catkin-packages:
      - hello_world
    rosdistro: kinetic
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're so close! Your snap isn't requesting access to the network, which by default snaps do not get. You do this by setting the `plugs` property of the app in question. Try making your `apps` section look like this:

```
apps:
  launch-project:
    command: roslaunch hello_world run_code.launch
    plugs: [network, network-bind]
```

Once you install that, run `snap interfaces` and you'll see both the `network` and `network-bind` plugs connected to the core's slot. To learn more about these, check out the [snapd interfaces wiki](https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/wiki/Interfaces).

As an extra exercise, once it's working, try disconnecting the interfaces:

```
sudo snap disconnect ros-example:network
sudo snap disconnect ros-example:network-bind
```

And run your app again. You should see it fail again with the same error.

As a final note, while you're developing/testing things out, remember you can install with `--devmode` to skip confinement: `sudo snap install --devmode <my snap>`.